# Why is my procedure returning a different value from my query?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

The procedure that is not returning correctly is the following:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`hs`@`%` PROCEDURE `GetUser_id`(in id int)
BEGIN
    select * from hackstart.users where ID=id;
END
```

which I call using

```
call GetUser_id(2);
```

I expect this to return the same as

```
select * from hackstart.users where `ID` = 2;
```

which returns a single row. However, the procedure returns the entire table. Can anyone point out where I went wrong and why it's incorrect.

Comment: it may be easier to identify parameters from columns by using a prefix? i.e.  `in p_id int` and: `select * from hackstart.users where ID = p_id;` ?

Comment: Variable input (ID) and column name `ID` have the same name.  change one of them or put the first ID in backticks to indicate it's a column from the database.  your present where is basically saying where 2=2 so all records.

Comment: thanks for the help, didn't realise that mysql wasn't case sensitive.

Comment: In my experience, it is generally not a good idea to use parameter names that are the same (ignoring case) as field names; it seems to confuse MySQL, and makes the proc itself harder to read.

Comment: As per case sensitivity mySQL relies heavily on the FileSystem: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html  but on an overabundance of caution, I'd use different names for variable and column name.

Comment: @xQbert Filename case sensitivity only applies to table names. Column names and variables are always case insensitive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Ryan and xQbert said, the issue was that the parameter had the same name as the column name, which is an issue due to case-insensitivity